# Changing List Value in C # Also Changes Your Copy Element

Tags: c#, list, object

I have a list of objects, and I'm passing them by parameter to a function. I want to edit it with some different values! because when I change an item from my list p does it change from the Pessons list, too? it's like accessing the same memory location, but I just want to replicate the list and alter it without causing changes to the other list.

```
 public void GerarPorLider(List<Person> Persons)
 {
     List<Person> p = Persons;
     p[0].Amount += 10;
 }
```

The output that is happening when I execute this code

> Persons[0].Amount = 17; p[0].Amount = 17;

The way I expected it

> Persons[0].Amount = 7; p[0].Amount = 17;

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
List<Person> p = Persons;
```

does not copy `Persons` list, it creates an alias for it. Any modification you make to `p` is actually a modification to `Persons` list, just by a different alias.

Moreover, `Person` objects inside the list would need to be copied, too.

Assuming that there is a constructor of `Person` that takes `Person` to copy, use this approach:

```
List<Person> p = Persons.Select(x => new Person(x)).ToList();
```

If `Person` does not have a copy constructor, copy it one property at a time:

```
List<Person> p = Persons.Select(x => new Person {
    // I am making up the properties of `Person` to be copied;
    // you need to use the actual ones.
    Name = x.Name
,   LastName = x.LastName
,   Address = x.Address
}).ToList();
```